# How can I get the first line and the 10th line from a string file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, request

I have the following code:

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.proxyscrape.com/v2/?request=getproxies&protocol=http&timeout=10000&country=all&ssl=all&anonymity=all'
r = requests.get(url)
proxy = r.text
for line in proxy:
    print(line)
```

The expected output should be the first line of the proxy list but that doesn't happen. If I use the following code:

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.proxyscrape.com/v2/?request=getproxies&protocol=http&timeout=10000&country=all&ssl=all&anonymity=all'
r = requests.get(url)
proxy = r.text
print(proxy)
```

I get this output:

```
161.35.176.77:8080
37.235.97.12:3128
104.248.174.93:8080
46.4.96.137:3128
52.35.63.184:8080
109.193.195.13:8080
138.199.30.140:3128
185.253.98.22:3128
85.214.94.28:3128
139.155.80.151:8000
5.252.161.48:3128
128.14.178.94:3128
47.242.78.34:8000
104.238.81.186:56220
161.35.216.229:8080
191.96.42.80:3128
109.193.195.8:8080
167.172.236.230:8080
207.144.111.230:8080
217.8.51.200:8080
185.253.98.18:3128
13.125.21.255:3128
188.166.30.17:8888
157.230.32.89:8080
37.49.127.232:8080
129.232.134.107:3128
78.42.42.40:8080
128.199.202.122:8080
176.113.73.95:3128
36.89.185.129:8080
94.130.179.24:8046
138.199.31.79:3128
191.96.71.118:3128
104.131.42.121:8080
163.172.47.182:3128
138.199.30.139:3128
89.221.223.234:80
222.129.35.51:57114
125.87.94.211:3256
36.91.51.233:3128
103.215.177.231:80
138.199.29.149:3128
88.198.24.108:3128
106.14.220.1:8080
175.146.211.196:9999
176.236.37.182:8080
45.230.169.129:999
165.227.187.158:3128
36.66.242.146:43936
152.204.128.46:33047
49.231.159.165:8080
193.105.107.156:8080
37.49.127.227:8080
78.42.42.34:8080
113.121.94.121:3256
36.67.168.117:80
139.5.71.46:23500
106.15.93.158:8080
176.113.157.149:42850
128.14.163.94:3128
187.60.160.131:8081
103.111.55.58:43525
117.24.80.97:3256
70.184.181.203:48678
183.165.11.109:3000
103.84.71.10:83
77.73.241.154:80
120.236.130.132:8060
176.12.124.68:8080
45.4.85.76:9991
34.244.243.224:80
91.90.121.235:3128
167.172.180.40:44129
138.199.31.81:3128
151.237.84.13:8080
138.199.30.147:3128
103.89.159.5:8080
195.9.173.38:63141
190.121.157.133:999
182.34.22.221:3256
186.159.5.161:8080
175.100.5.52:32721
139.59.1.14:8080
161.199.130.1:8080
106.14.22.184:8080
77.247.89.254:8080
109.193.195.10:8080
14.102.152.158:8080
59.55.165.180:3256
91.195.205.39:8080
93.87.82.222:3128
109.193.195.6:8080
190.57.143.66:50719
139.255.25.106:8080
138.199.29.156:3128
167.172.109.12:34527
200.60.79.11:53281
82.212.62.24:8080
45.118.166.114:8080
186.149.103.227:999
203.112.76.193:8080
103.14.199.30:82
157.119.50.118:8080
103.52.220.106:83
134.209.98.28:8080
47.90.132.228:8080
103.157.116.199:8080
142.44.148.56:8080
1.10.189.133:40569
103.78.141.27:8080
103.16.133.17:8080
178.93.46.93:8080
188.136.174.23:3128
115.75.1.184:8118
195.182.152.238:38178
167.172.109.12:44425
54.39.51.99:3128
91.242.38.9:3128
212.102.53.83:3128
134.3.255.2:8080
202.165.47.26:8080
45.167.124.205:999
85.216.127.182:8080
187.243.253.2:8080
116.117.134.134:8828
177.37.175.222:8080
212.102.52.2:3128
178.151.205.154:45099
190.121.146.68:999
168.195.140.239:8080
109.122.88.50:8080
150.129.56.138:31111
195.78.112.235:42549
118.172.155.177:8080
184.180.90.226:8080
106.14.203.191:8080
138.121.161.162:999
160.20.166.193:999
139.224.46.85:8080
181.113.135.254:52058
185.38.111.1:8080
95.58.145.22:8080
177.73.44.169:8080
61.14.228.126:8080
5.15.46.139:8080
123.139.56.171:9999
62.201.226.186:8080
118.179.173.253:40836
112.169.9.162:80
157.230.241.211:8080
106.14.171.72:8080
78.83.199.235:53281
103.243.82.198:37358
119.82.252.25:42914
212.102.52.6:3128
122.15.211.124:80
95.208.208.235:8080
187.188.169.169:8080
125.78.227.41:4216
109.245.239.125:35659
118.137.76.146:8080
176.235.99.12:9090
122.155.165.191:3128
187.41.24.214:8080
60.173.35.63:3256
14.97.2.104:80
220.174.236.211:8091
101.132.126.161:8080
138.199.31.67:3128
203.202.245.102:3137
187.44.167.78:60786
80.191.174.220:8080
172.105.252.178:8080
117.4.145.16:51487
187.49.80.85:6006
178.168.67.89:4645
106.14.41.100:8080
103.216.147.33:8080
54.151.186.254:80
221.131.158.246:8888
114.112.127.20:80
185.138.113.143:8080
87.255.13.217:8080
115.85.73.179:3128
115.77.191.25:9090
102.141.197.17:8080
193.242.142.6:8080
213.105.29.14:3128
85.216.127.183:8080
103.11.106.25:8181
95.31.5.29:54651
203.243.63.16:80
103.80.83.48:3127
8.133.191.41:80
110.90.222.21:4216
84.17.51.212:3128
217.8.51.198:8080
161.35.4.201:80
187.95.114.125:3128
93.114.133.153:3128
117.102.81.4:53281
181.48.111.246:49094
82.212.62.22:8080
88.99.134.61:8080
163.204.93.71:9999
202.153.231.52:8181
154.127.38.1:60020
27.43.184.99:9999
178.33.251.230:3129
88.198.167.20:8138
144.76.179.71:8080
125.62.197.33:83
78.42.42.35:3128
212.102.52.10:3128
138.199.29.155:3128
114.110.21.121:50464
183.6.183.35:3128
36.67.86.183:8080
185.189.252.121:35939
51.254.237.77:3129
45.230.171.80:999
41.217.242.11:8080
190.4.200.146:999
154.72.197.106:42113
154.117.159.228:8080
122.224.65.197:3128
202.169.56.100:8080
190.89.40.5:999
178.134.157.215:8080
200.88.166.179:999
217.195.203.29:3131
101.200.233.169:8081
187.44.1.172:8080
43.224.10.19:6666
103.213.116.198:8080
117.102.81.6:53281
103.14.234.45:8080
68.183.188.73:8080
125.78.228.224:4216
212.102.52.5:3128
106.45.220.70:3256
205.201.49.132:53281
157.119.48.17:8080
195.158.3.198:3128
103.199.84.122:8080
212.89.188.115:21231
106.14.168.249:8080
129.205.106.42:8080
193.86.229.230:8080
103.251.225.18:35101
113.123.0.131:3256
103.19.129.10:82
167.172.180.46:33428
37.221.204.206:47424
50.233.42.98:51696
36.67.11.41:8080
1.10.179.195:8080
49.204.79.85:80
27.153.143.55:4216
13.229.47.109:80
46.5.252.61:8080
91.207.184.105:53281
5.9.139.148:8080
117.102.92.10:8080
176.103.33.188:8080
179.1.1.85:999
203.23.49.124:80
88.198.24.108:8080
178.252.179.12:8080
50.206.25.109:80
36.67.251.241:41271
167.172.109.12:36767
144.91.85.172:3128
90.183.101.238:45277
106.14.77.244:8000
103.15.60.225:8080
154.16.63.16:3128
176.236.157.149:8080
159.65.112.248:8888
138.199.30.137:3128
160.20.206.199:999
186.159.3.41:30334
103.148.210.110:8080
193.140.135.230:80
196.2.14.250:45521
116.117.134.134:9999
95.208.208.232:8080
103.151.226.133:8080
200.155.139.242:3128
185.192.124.11:3128
45.55.56.181:8080
117.102.87.138:41757
217.8.51.197:8080
88.119.130.181:9999
159.192.149.80:8080
102.129.249.120:8080
43.224.220.27:8080
150.129.148.99:35101
101.132.39.75:8080
181.48.38.20:8080
185.12.69.174:8080
84.17.51.209:3128
122.246.92.54:3256
121.232.194.222:3256
167.172.109.12:38156
78.42.42.42:8080
168.138.219.129:3128
36.92.83.178:8080
85.216.127.186:3128
103.137.218.1:83
176.9.85.13:3128
123.108.200.137:83
103.148.79.120:8080
5.16.0.186:8080
118.212.107.18:9999
193.226.199.110:32231
212.95.180.50:53281
109.170.96.26:8080
122.15.131.65:57873
200.217.153.246:8080
101.132.116.117:8080
190.210.8.93:8080
187.45.24.74:3128
45.250.226.53:8080
190.103.85.37:8080
175.106.12.243:8089
37.24.184.227:8080
82.212.62.20:8080
51.75.147.44:3128
36.94.130.178:80
139.196.113.79:8080
170.238.11.40:999
51.81.82.175:80
89.237.33.113:37647
66.82.65.41:87
51.159.24.172:3161
118.199.1.121:80
191.243.218.249:53281
31.28.228.252:8080
190.185.116.161:999
212.102.52.8:3128
190.83.12.231:999
117.102.81.5:53281
103.22.248.59:61661
95.215.48.93:8080
13.228.25.153:80
110.89.121.94:3256
186.225.113.242:8080
103.120.144.144:80
96.9.86.70:53827
185.8.60.104:8080
202.143.125.220:8080
173.212.202.65:80
41.217.219.53:31398
181.114.224.177:8080
221.182.31.54:8080
120.42.132.66:3256
5.16.0.169:8080
49.70.151.254:3256
91.137.238.14:8082
45.70.15.9:8080
202.75.97.82:47009
180.149.98.126:8080
212.102.53.86:3128
117.42.37.121:3256
187.190.226.53:9991
176.236.157.147:8080
113.121.38.161:9999
94.158.157.143:8080
111.177.192.58:3256
181.129.183.19:53281
103.14.198.145:83
161.35.70.249:3128
45.174.92.2:999
188.166.89.10:8080
80.65.28.57:30962
190.90.191.53:999
157.230.103.189:36938
185.131.60.17:8080
195.178.56.33:8080
138.117.85.231:999
103.217.213.125:55443
41.164.243.177:8080
84.17.51.213:3128
181.188.166.82:8080
36.66.206.74:8080
46.246.86.4:3128
84.53.247.204:53281
134.209.29.120:3128
101.132.162.193:8080
85.198.185.26:8080
202.61.49.52:47448
111.235.65.211:45811
103.44.156.53:8080
89.211.201.53:8080
79.137.44.85:3129
185.94.218.57:43403
182.87.239.181:3000
101.255.125.10:8080
218.6.105.64:4216
62.201.253.66:8080
62.201.217.194:8080
138.68.60.8:3128
187.45.127.87:20183
45.231.221.1:999
122.15.211.125:80
36.89.234.175:8080
139.224.47.214:8080
138.117.85.153:999
94.242.59.20:3128
222.129.36.153:57114
193.106.130.249:8080
185.108.141.114:8080
203.202.245.58:80
103.195.2.42:8080
114.104.134.132:3256
167.71.5.83:8080
177.130.140.80:8080
150.129.207.75:35101
116.117.134.134:80
103.154.160.58:8080
168.196.192.114:3128
89.208.35.81:3128
103.123.66.114:8080
103.109.57.161:8080
103.226.170.134:83
181.196.142.114:8888
193.232.252.38:8080
121.205.220.50:4216
163.172.47.182:8080
45.70.196.137:999
89.147.203.190:3128
103.11.106.70:8181
36.249.52.22:9999
217.195.203.30:3128
178.172.208.4:32231
81.18.34.98:42535
45.224.149.180:999
154.66.245.47:46611
37.18.61.247:8080
180.211.183.2:8080
198.211.100.174:3128
131.161.237.78:8090
187.190.114.42:3128
36.89.99.98:44030
80.53.65.230:8080
190.109.169.41:53281
41.220.114.154:8080
103.42.253.210:38812
159.89.221.73:3128
181.10.160.157:8080
131.161.68.37:31264
103.126.87.150:8080
120.232.150.110:80
103.81.214.9:83
37.235.96.199:3128
181.39.48.2:80
193.34.95.110:8080
190.95.214.183:8080
62.219.33.53:8080
114.5.199.200:8182
183.166.132.61:3256
106.14.13.46:8080
117.69.151.99:3256
111.68.31.154:8080
114.239.31.228:3256
64.139.79.35:8080
85.26.146.169:80
223.243.174.144:3256
151.22.181.222:8080
80.244.229.199:8080
175.146.214.226:9999
190.248.154.2:9992
176.9.119.170:3128
183.88.91.169:8080
14.161.10.191:8080
8.133.191.41:8080
186.183.220.2:8080
202.43.183.210:80
197.255.209.34:8080
106.14.10.111:8080
120.194.42.157:38185
112.74.101.239:39746
202.90.141.145:3128
212.46.255.78:8080
41.65.201.179:8080
138.97.200.92:8080
5.189.133.231:80
202.180.54.97:8080
103.111.55.58:184
36.92.107.194:8080
120.29.124.131:8080
103.122.65.210:3127
178.252.179.11:8080
182.52.90.42:51657
88.255.218.5:8080
45.64.179.242:53281
128.199.218.83:8080
185.123.143.244:3128
175.44.108.8:9999
103.49.54.129:83
103.84.69.233:84
116.0.54.30:8080
191.100.20.187:8080
180.180.170.188:8080
84.17.51.210:3128
109.105.205.232:59152
41.190.92.84:48515
95.0.219.201:8080
116.196.85.150:3128
138.199.29.145:3128
190.149.165.162:51489
125.109.198.180:3256
36.94.37.66:8080
182.23.54.211:54525
198.199.86.11:3128
186.219.50.11:8080
88.198.50.103:3128
157.230.103.189:43794
66.42.53.102:8080
116.202.108.45:8008
165.16.96.91:8080
195.190.123.236:8080
182.253.169.195:8080
41.75.4.208:53281
145.239.121.218:3129
27.155.220.159:4216
51.159.24.172:3166
198.50.163.192:3129
191.241.226.230:53281
103.224.5.5:54143
```

What can I do to get the first and 10th lines from the proxy list? I tried iterating over them using a for loop but that just gives me this output:

```
9
.
1
9
3
.
1
9
5
.
2
:
8
0
8
0



1
8
5
.
8
.
6
0
.
1
3
6
:
8
0
8
0



1
6
2
.
1
5
5
.
1
0
.
1
5
0
:
5
5
4
4
3



1
9
3
.
8
5
.
2
2
8
.
1
7
8
:
4
3
0
3
6



5
1
.
9
1
.
2
0
1
.
5
5
:
8
0
8
0



1
1
6
.
1
1
7
.
1
3
4
.
1
3
4
:
8
2



3
6
.
9
4
.
1
4
2
.
1
6
3
:
8
0
0
0



1
8
3
.
1
6
6
.
1
3
3
.
1
7
1
:
3
0
0
0



9
0
.
1
8
3
.
1
0
1
.
2
3
8
:
4
5
2
7
7



7
8
.
1
1
1
.
1
0
6
.
3
6
:
3
1
2
8



1
8
5
.
2
0
4
.
2
1
6
.
7
0
:
3
1
2
8



8
9
.
2
2
1
.
2
2
3
.
2
3
4
:
8
0



1
7
8
.
2
5
2
.
1
7
9
.
1
2
:
8
0
8
0



2
0
2
.
4
7
.
6
6
.
6
0
:
8
0



1
5
7
.
2
4
5
.
9
7
.
2
1
0
:
8
0
8
0



3
6
.
8
9
.
1
2
6
.
1
8
3
:
8
0
8
0



5
.
1
6
.
0
.
1
6
9
:
8
0
8
0



1
1
1
.
1
7
7
.
1
9
2
.
6
6
:
3
2
5
6



4
6
.
2
3
7
.
2
5
5
.
2
:
8
0
8
0



4
5
.
7
0
.
1
2
.
6
6
:
9
9
9



1
6
7
.
1
7
2
.
2
3
6
.
2
3
0
:
8
0
8
0



1
4
9
.
1
7
2
.
2
5
5
.
7
:
8
0
8
0



1
0
3
.
2
0
5
.
1
5
.
9
7
:
8
0
8
0



2
1
2
.
1
0
2
.
5
3
.
8
5
:
3
1
2
8



3
6
.
9
2
.
1
7
8
.
9
9
:
5
5
4
4
3



9
4
.
2
4
4
.
2
8
.
2
4
6
:
3
1
2
8
0



1
8
6
.
1
8
3
.
2
2
0
.
1
8
6
:
8
0
8
0



5
1
.
2
5
5
.
1
0
3
.
1
7
0
:
3
1
2
9



2
1
2
.
1
0
2
.
5
2
.
2
:
3
1
2
8



4
5
.
2
2
4
.
2
2
.
6
6
:
9
9
9



2
1
2
.
3
3
.
2
0
5
.
1
2
1
:
8
0
8
0



7
9
.
1
3
7
.
4
4
.
8
5
:
3
1
2
9



9
5
.
1
1
1
.
1
3
4
.
1
2
2
:
3
2
3
4
5



1
8
5
.
2
3
.
1
3
1
.
1
8
3
:
8
0
8
0



1
3
9
.
1
9
6
.
1
5
2
.
2
2
1
:
8
0
8
0



1
8
5
.
2
3
.
1
3
1
.
1
2
4
:
8
0
8
0



1
2
0
.
8
3
.
1
0
4
.
4
0
:
9
9
9
9



1
6
3
.
1
7
2
.
4
7
.
1
8
2
:
8
0
8
0



1
8
8
.
1
6
6
.
8
9
.
1
0
:
8
0
8
0



1
0
4
.
2
2
5
.
1
6
1
.
3
:
8
0



2
7
.
1
4
8
.
2
4
8
.
2
0
3
:
8
0



9
2
.
2
4
5
.
1
4
2
.
2
1
5
:
8
0
8
0



8
8
.
1
9
8
.
2
4
.
1
0
8
:
8
0
8
0



4
5
.
1
7
9
.
2
4
5
.
1
:
9
9
9



3
6
.
3
7
.
1
3
9
.
2
:
4
3
9
9
7



7
2
.
2
5
2
.
4
.
2
5
0
:
8
0
8
0



3
.
1
3
9
.
5
7
.
1
5
:
3
1
2
8



1
0
6
.
1
4
.
2
4
3
.
1
6
7
:
8
0
8
0



1
1
7
.
2
4
5
.
1
3
9
.
4
:
8
0
8
0



1
3
4
.
3
.
2
5
5
.
9
:
8
0
8
0



4
1
.
2
0
2
.
2
2
1
.
1
0
2
:
8
0
8
0



3
7
.
1
5
2
.
1
8
2
.
6
5
:
3
1
2
8



1
3
8
.
1
9
9
.
3
0
.
1
4
4
:
3
1
2
8



1
7
8
.
2
5
2
.
1
9
0
.
1
9
4
:
3
1
2
8



1
8
2
.
1
6
.
1
8
6
.
2
1
8
:
8
0
8
0



1
6
7
.
2
4
9
.
1
8
1
.
2
3
6
:
8
0
8
0



1
7
0
.
2
3
8
.
1
1
.
3
0
:
9
9
9



2
1
7
.
8
.
5
1
.
1
9
7
:
8
0
8
0



1
2
0
.
7
8
.
2
1
7
.
9
8
:
3
2
2
8



1
3
8
.
6
8
.
6
0
.
8
:
3
1
2
8



2
0
2
.
1
6
9
.
4
7
.
1
0
8
:
8
0
8
0



1
7
0
.
2
3
1
.
1
8
7
.
2
0
9
:
8
0
9
1



1
3
8
.
1
9
9
.
2
9
.
1
5
8
:
3
1
2
8



3
6
.
6
6
.
2
4
2
.
1
4
8
:
4
3
9
3
6



4
5
.
1
7
4
.
2
4
0
.
5
4
:
9
9
9



1
8
1
.
2
2
5
.
7
3
.
1
1
:
8
0
8
0



1
0
3
.
1
3
4
.
2
1
3
.
5
2
:
8
0
8
0



4
6
.
4
.
9
6
.
1
3
7
:
3
1
2
8



9
5
.
2
0
8
.
2
0
8
.
2
3
4
:
8
0
8
0



7
8
.
4
2
.
4
2
.
4
0
:
8
0
8
0



1
2
1
.
5
2
.
7
1
.
2
3
:
8
0



1
8
5
.
1
3
3
.
4
2
.
9
8
:
3
1
2
8



1
6
7
.
1
7
2
.
1
0
9
.
1
2
:
3
8
1
5
6



1
.
2
0
.
9
7
.
1
8
1
:
5
5
2
8
5



1
8
9
.
1
9
3
.
1
9
8
.
7
9
:
8
0
8
0



1
0
4
.
1
3
1
.
1
1
2
.
7
4
:
8
0



1
6
7
.
7
1
.
4
1
.
1
7
3
:
4
4
7
6
1



4
6
.
5
.
2
5
2
.
5
9
:
3
1
2
8



9
1
.
1
4
2
.
1
7
4
.
2
2
4
:
4
1
5
7
6



1
6
0
.
2
3
8
.
2
2
7
.
1
5
3
:
3
0
2
2
2



1
3
9
.
5
9
.
1
.
1
4
:
8
0
8
0



1
8
8
.
1
6
6
.
1
0
3
.
1
3
5
:
8
0
8
0



3
6
.
6
7
.
8
9
.
1
7
9
:
6
5
2
0
5



1
8
5
.
1
5
.
1
1
0
.
1
0
6
:
8
0
8
0



1
2
5
.
2
7
.
2
5
1
.
2
0
6
:
5
0
8
1
7



1
0
6
.
1
4
.
1
7
5
.
8
:
8
0
8
0



9
1
.
1
9
2
.
2
.
1
6
8
:
5
3
2
8
1



1
8
0
.
2
5
0
.
1
5
3
.
1
2
9
:
5
3
2
8
1



2
1
7
.
2
1
9
.
6
1
.
6
:
8
0
8
0



4
5
.
4
.
8
5
.
1
5
2
:
9
9
9
1



1
8
3
.
8
8
.
2
.
2
1
0
:
8
0
8
0



1
0
6
.
1
4
.
4
1
.
1
0
5
:
8
0
8
0



1
7
8
.
1
3
4
.
2
0
8
.
1
2
6
:
5
0
8
2
4



1
8
5
.
3
.
2
1
3
.
8
:
8
0
8
0



1
0
3
.
2
5
0
.
6
9
.
2
3
3
:
8
0
8
0



1
0
3
.
1
1
1
.
5
5
.
5
8
:
1
5
2



1
0
9
.
1
9
3
.
1
9
5
.
1
3
:
8
0
8
0



9
5
.
1
4
1
.
3
6
.
1
1
2
:
8
6
8
6



1
0
3
.
4
7
.
6
7
.
1
1
6
:
8
0
8
0



1
7
6
.
1
1
3
.
7
3
.
9
5
:
3
1
2
8



8
1
.
1
2
.
1
1
9
.
1
8
9
:
8
0
8
0



1
2
.
1
5
6
.
4
5
.
1
5
5
:
3
1
2
8



1
6
9
.
2
5
5
.
7
5
.
1
1
7
:
3
4
4
0
3



1
8
2
.
3
4
.
2
2
.
2
2
1
:
3
2
5
6



2
0
2
.
1
6
4
.
1
5
2
.
2
3
3
:
8
0
8
0



1
0
3
.
2
2
.
1
7
2
.
4
9
:
5
9
4
5
8



1
3
8
.
1
9
9
.
3
0
.
1
3
7
:
3
1
2
8



2
0
1
.
2
3
4
.
6
0
.
1
0
:
9
9
9



1
2
2
.
2
4
6
.
9
3
.
1
5
2
:
3
2
5
6



1
0
1
.
1
0
9
.
2
5
5
.
1
7
:
4
3
5
0
1



1
7
7
.
4
4
.
8
2
.
2
3
2
:
8
0
8
0



7
8
.
1
1
.
8
5
.
1
5
:
8
0
8
0



3
6
.
6
7
.
1
6
8
.
1
1
7
:
8
0



1
0
3
.
1
0
4
.
2
9
.
1
4
1
:
8
0
8
0



1
9
1
.
9
7
.
1
8
.
1
6
1
:
9
9
9



1
.
3
2
.
4
9
.
2
2
2
:
8
0
8
0



1
0
3
.
8
4
.
6
9
.
2
3
3
:
8
4



1
0
3
.
7
0
.
7
9
.
3
:
8
0
8
0



8
8
.
1
9
8
.
1
6
7
.
2
0
:
8
1
2
8



4
9
.
8
5
.
1
6
3
.
1
1
:
3
2
5
6



7
8
.
4
2
.
4
2
.
4
4
:
3
1
2
8



1
7
6
.
2
3
5
.
1
8
2
.
7
9
:
8
0
8
0



4
5
.
2
2
8
.
1
8
8
.
5
:
9
9
9



6
1
.
1
6
3
.
3
2
.
8
8
:
3
1
2
8



1
0
3
.
2
4
1
.
2
2
7
.
1
1
4
:
6
6
6
6



7
8
.
4
2
.
4
2
.
4
5
:
8
0
8
0



1
7
8
.
2
1
5
.
1
9
0
.
2
4
0
:
5
9
5
4
1



8
2
.
2
0
0
.
1
8
1
.
5
4
:
3
1
2
9



1
6
8
.
1
9
5
.
1
4
0
.
2
3
9
:
8
0
8
0



9
4
.
1
3
0
.
4
9
.
1
5
1
:
3
1
2
8



1
8
2
.
2
5
3
.
2
4
4
.
1
3
3
:
1
0
8
0



5
.
2
5
2
.
1
6
1
.
4
8
:
8
0
8
0



1
9
5
.
9
.
1
1
4
.
2
2
2
:
6
3
1
4
1



1
7
6
.
9
8
.
9
5
.
1
0
5
:
3
2
0
1
8



6
1
.
1
5
0
.
9
6
.
2
7
:
3
6
8
8
0



2
1
3
.
2
3
2
.
1
2
6
.
2
5
0
:
8
0



1
3
6
.
2
3
3
.
2
1
5
.
1
3
9
:
8
0



1
3
9
.
1
5
5
.
8
0
.
1
5
1
:
8
0
0
0



1
2
8
.
1
4
.
1
7
8
.
9
4
:
3
1
2
8



4
7
.
2
4
2
.
7
8
.
3
4
:
8
0
0
0



1
0
4
.
2
3
8
.
8
1
.
1
8
6
:
5
6
2
2
0



1
0
6
.
1
4
.
1
7
1
.
7
2
:
8
0
8
0



2
1
7
.
8
.
5
1
.
2
0
0
:
8
0
8
0



3
4
.
6
4
.
1
1
4
.
1
7
1
:
8
0



3
7
.
4
9
.
1
2
7
.
2
3
2
:
8
0
8
0



1
1
0
.
8
6
.
1
8
2
.
2
5
3
:
4
2
1
6



3
6
.
9
1
.
5
1
.
2
3
3
:
3
1
2
8



8
8
.
1
9
8
.
2
4
.
1
0
8
:
3
1
2
8



1
7
6
.
2
3
6
.
3
7
.
1
8
2
:
8
0
8
0



1
6
5
.
2
2
7
.
1
8
7
.
1
5
8
:
3
1
2
8



1
5
2
.
2
0
4
.
1
2
8
.
4
6
:
3
3
0
4
7



7
0
.
1
8
4
.
1
8
1
.
2
0
3
:
4
8
6
7
8



1
9
5
.
9
.
1
7
3
.
3
8
:
6
3
1
4
1



1
0
2
.
1
3
0
.
1
2
2
.
5
6
:
8
8
8
8



1
2
3
.
2
0
0
.
6
.
2
2
6
:
8
0
8
0



1
7
7
.
2
2
.
8
9
.
2
0
2
:
3
1
2
8



3
7
.
4
9
.
1
2
7
.
2
2
9
:
8
0
8
0



2
7
.
1
5
5
.
2
2
0
.
1
9
1
:
4
2
1
6



8
1
.
1
6
3
.
6
2
.
2
2
1
:
3
4
0
1
1



1
8
6
.
3
.
1
3
8
.
5
6
:
8
0
8
0



1
1
9
.
1
1
0
.
2
0
9
.
9
4
:
3
1
2
8



3
6
.
9
1
.
9
7
.
2
2
8
:
8
0
8
0



1
8
5
.
2
5
3
.
9
8
.
2
1
:
3
1
2
8



8
2
.
2
1
2
.
6
2
.
2
7
:
8
0
8
0



2
0
9
.
1
2
6
.
4
.
1
3
4
:
3
1
2
8



6
1
.
7
.
1
4
1
.
3
0
:
8
0
8
0



1
7
6
.
1
1
3
.
7
3
.
1
0
0
:
3
1
2
8



1
3
9
.
2
5
5
.
1
1
0
.
2
0
2
:
8
0
8
0



4
6
.
5
.
2
5
2
.
5
0
:
3
1
2
8



1
8
1
.
1
1
2
.
1
5
4
.
1
2
4
:
8
0
8
0



1
0
1
.
1
3
2
.
1
0
5
.
8
4
:
8
0
8
0



1
2
3
.
2
5
.
1
2
1
.
1
5
2
:
8
0
8
0



3
1
.
2
8
.
9
9
.
2
5
:
3
1
3
9
6



1
8
1
.
1
4
3
.
1
0
6
.
1
6
2
:
5
2
1
5
1



1
0
3
.
2
1
.
1
6
1
.
1
0
5
:
6
6
6
6



4
6
.
5
.
2
5
2
.
7
0
:
8
0
8
0
```

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking. The title is about a *file*, the code is about a request body/text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The returned response is a `str` object.

You can use `splitlines()` to split on new line character and take the desired element:

```
proxy = """161.35.176.77:8080
37.235.97.12:3128
104.248.174.93:8080
46.4.96.137:3128
52.35.63.184:8080
109.193.195.13:8080
138.199.30.140:3128
185.253.98.22:3128
85.214.94.28:3128
139.155.80.151:8000
5.252.161.48:3128
128.14.178.94:3128
47.242.78.34:8000
104.238.81.186:56220
161.35.216.229:8080
191.96.42.80:3128
109.193.195.8:8080
167.172.236.230:8080
207.144.111.230:8080
217.8.51.200:8080
185.253.98.18:3128
13.125.21.255:3128
188.166.30.17:8888"""

proxies = proxy.splitlines()
first = proxies[0].strip()
tenth = proxies[9].strip()
print(first)
print(tenth)
```

Output:

```
161.35.176.77:8080
139.155.80.151:8000
```

---

Update: Iterating over the list of proxies using a loop:

```
proxies = proxy.splitlines()
for pxy in proxies:
    print(pxy)
```

Subset of output:

```
161.35.176.77:8080
37.235.97.12:3128
104.248.174.93:8080
46.4.96.137:3128
52.35.63.184:8080
109.193.195.13:8080
138.199.30.140:3128
185.253.98.22:3128
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the .text attribute/property returns a string or similar object with newlines between the IP addresses, you seem to want a list.

Try this:

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.proxyscrape.com/v2/?request=getproxies&protocol=http&timeout=10000&country=all&ssl=all&anonymity=all'
r = requests.get(url)
proxy = str(r.text)
proxy = proxy.splitlines()
print(f'{proxy[0]} \n {proxy[9]}')
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! By any chance do you know if it's possible to add that to a while loop? So that the proxy changes to another line on every iteration?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, which line do you want it to change to?

Answer (score -1):

You should use the split method which returns a list of the words in the string (https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/split.html).

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.proxyscrape.com/v2/?request=getproxies&protocol=http&timeout=10000&country=all&ssl=all&anonymity=all'
r = requests.get(url)
proxy = r.text.split()
print(proxy[10])
```

Output:

```
165.22.126.200:8080
```